# Multiplicar filas de tablas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hice una tabla en la que en las etiquetas

Puedo escribir números(para multiplicarlos) y en otra  poder mostrar el resultado, me funciona solo cuando tengo una fila [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si agrego otra fila con sus columnas debajo ya no me muestra el resultado por cada fila [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se dan cuenta 14* 13 =182 
              y  13*2 =  26 
Solo me muestra el resultado de la ultima operación

Quisiera que me ayuden a hacer que en la columna del resultado, se muestre el resultado correcto de cada multiplicación, aquí les dejo mi código, gracias de antemano y espero haber sido claro ya que no soy bueno explicando

**HTML**

```html
<table  width="600" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="7"> 
 <tr class="tabla">
    <td >numero 1</td>
   <td >numero 2</td>
   <td>resultado</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="tabla">
  <td id="" onkeyup="myFunction()" contenteditable></td>
 <td id="" onkeyup="myFunction()" contenteditable></td>
 <td class="total"></td>
</tr>

<tr class="tabla">
  <td id="" onkeyup="myFunction()" contenteditable></td>
 <td id="" onkeyup="myFunction()" contenteditable></td>
 <td class="total"></td>
</tr>

</table>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function myFunction() {    
    $('.tabla').each(function() {
        var _1 = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();
        var _2 = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html();

        var _11=parseInt(_1);
        var _22=parseInt(_2);

  var total= _11 * _22 ;
  if( isNaN(total)){
    $('.total').html(0) ;
  }else{
    $('.total').html(total) ;
  }
    
  
  
 
});

}   
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema se encuentra en que estas recorriendo todos los td, multiplicas el primero y el segundo, pero el resultado lo muestras en todos los .total de la tabla. Con lo que te repite y muestra vaya a saber cual de todas las multiplicaciones.

Quizás aplicando de la siguiente manera

```html
<table  width="600" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="7">
        <tr class="tabla">
            <td >numero 1</td>
            <td >numero 2</td>
            <td>resultado</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tabla" onkeyup="myFunction(this)">
            <td id=""  contenteditable>11</td>
            <td id="" contenteditable>22</td>
            <td class="total"></td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr class="tabla" onkeyup="myFunction(this)">
            <td id=""  contenteditable></td>
            <td id=""  contenteditable></td>
            <td class="total"></td>
        </tr>
    
    </table>
    
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        function myFunction(o) {
    /*        $('.tabla').each(function() {
                var _1 = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();
                var _2 = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html();
    
                var _11=parseInt(_1);
                var _22=parseInt(_2);
    
                var total= _11 * _22 ;
                if( isNaN(total)){
                    $('.total').html(0) ;
                }else{
                    $('.total').html(total) ;
                }
    
            });*/
            var _tr = $(o);
            var _1 = _tr.find("td").eq(0).html();
            var _2 = _tr.find("td").eq(1).html();
            var _11=parseInt(_1);
            var _22=parseInt(_2);
            var total= _11 * _22 ;
            console.log(total);
            var _total = _tr.find("td").eq(2);
            if( isNaN(total)){
                _total.html(0) ;
            }else{
                _total.html(total) ;
            }
    
        }
    </script>
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: gracias si funciona con dos ...pero como haria si tengo muchas , alguna forma de hacerlo con un cliclo for o while? ....muchas gracias

Comment: haaaa, ya revise funciona con muchas

Comment: esta genial ,muchas gracias en verdad

Comment: No hay problema

Comment: Les sugiero que también le agreguen decimales yo hice la prueba y no me da los decimales y si son muy necesarios, aún así muy buen trabajo.